# Multithreading computation of Mandelbrot set

Tags: c++, multithreading, fractals, mandelbrot

I have created a program which creates a `Mandelbrot` set. Now I'm trying to make it multithreaded.

```
// mandelbrot.cpp
// compile with: g++ -std=c++11 mandelbrot.cpp -o mandelbrot
// view output with: eog mandelbrot.ppm

#include <fstream>
#include <complex> // if you make use of complex number facilities in C++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

template <class T> struct RGB { T r, g, b; };

template <class T>
class Matrix {
public:
Matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols) : _rows(rows), _cols(cols) {
    _matrix = new T*[rows];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        _matrix[i] = new T[cols];
    }
}
Matrix(const Matrix &m) : _rows(m._rows), _cols(m._cols) {
    _matrix = new T*[m._rows];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m._rows; ++i) {
        _matrix[i] = new T[m._cols];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m._cols; ++j) {
            _matrix[i][j] = m._matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
~Matrix() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _rows; ++i) {
        delete [] _matrix[i];
    }
    delete [] _matrix;
}
T *operator[] (const size_t nIndex)
{
    return _matrix[nIndex];
}
size_t width() const { return _cols; }
size_t height() const { return _rows; }
protected:
size_t _rows, _cols;
T **_matrix;
};

// Portable PixMap image
class PPMImage : public Matrix<RGB<unsigned char> >
{
public:
   unsigned int size; 

PPMImage(const size_t height, const size_t width) : Matrix(height, width) { }
void save(const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
    out <<"P6" << std::endl << _cols << " " << _rows << std::endl << 255 << std::endl;
    for (size_t y=0; y<_rows; y++)
        for (size_t x=0; x<_cols; x++) 
            out << _matrix[y][x].r << _matrix[y][x].g << _matrix[y][x].b;
}    
};

/*Draw mandelbrot according to the provided parameters*/
void draw_Mandelbrot(PPMImage & image, const unsigned width, const unsigned height, double cxmin, double cxmax, double cymin, double cymax,unsigned int max_iterations)                         
{

for (std::size_t ix = 0; ix < width; ++ix)
    for (std::size_t iy = 0; iy < height; ++iy)
    {
        std::complex<double> c(cxmin + ix / (width - 1.0)*(cxmax - cxmin), cymin + iy / (height - 1.0)*(cymax - cymin));
        std::complex<double> z = 0;
        unsigned int iterations;

        for (iterations = 0; iterations < max_iterations && std::abs(z) < 2.0; ++iterations)
            z = z*z + c;

        image[iy][ix].r = image[iy][ix].g = image[iy][ix].b = iterations;

    }
}

int main()
{
const unsigned width = 1600;
const unsigned height = 1600;

PPMImage image(height, width);


int parts = 8;

std::vector<int>bnd (parts, image.size);

std::thread *tt = new std::thread[parts - 1];

time_t start, end;
time(&start);
//Lauch parts-1 threads
for (int i = 0; i < parts - 1; ++i) {
    tt[i] = std::thread(draw_Mandelbrot,ref(image), width, height, -2.0, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0, 10);
}

//Use the main thread to do part of the work !!!
for (int i = parts - 1; i < parts; ++i) {
    draw_Mandelbrot(ref(image), width, height, -2.0, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0, 10);
}

//Join parts-1 threads
for (int i = 0; i < parts - 1; ++i)
    tt[i].join();

time(&end);
std::cout << difftime(end, start) << " seconds" << std::endl;


image.save("mandelbrot.ppm");

delete[] tt;

return 0;
}
```

Now every `thread` draws the complete fractal (look in `main()`). How can I let the threads draw different parts of the fractal?

Comment: Related (Java): [Multi-threading Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660429/multi-threading-java)

Comment: Basic arithmetic; figure out the bounds of each part, pass those and the corresponding x and y bounds to the threads. You'll need to add the coordinates for one of the corners to the thread function. I would recommend that you first do it single-threadedly (by calling the function from `main`) so you don't have to fix both math problems and threading problems simultaneously..

Comment: @molbdnilo do you have an example of that?

Comment: @Sybren An example of *maths*?

Comment: @molbdnilo no, an example where something similar as you explain is done in C++.

Comment: Can we narrow this question down? Are you asking how to pass arguments to a thread, or are you asking how to work out what those arguments are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making this (quite a lot) harder than it needs to be. This is the sort of task to which OpenMP is almost perfectly suited. For this task it gives almost perfect scaling with a *bare* minimum of effort.

I modified your `draw_mandelbrot` by inserting a pragma before the outer `for` loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int ix = 0; ix < width; ++ix)
    for (int iy = 0; iy < height; ++iy)
```

Then I simplified your `main` down to:

```
int main() {
    const unsigned width = 1600;
    const unsigned height = 1600;

    PPMImage image(height, width);

    clock_t start = clock();
    draw_Mandelbrot(image, width, height, -2.0, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0, 10);
    clock_t stop = clock();

    std::cout << (double(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " seconds\n";

    image.save("mandelbrot.ppm");

    return 0;
}
```

On my (fairly slow) machine, your original code ran in 4.73 seconds. My modified code ran in 1.38 seconds. That's an improvement of 3.4x out of code that's nearly indistinguishable from a trivial single-threaded version.

Just for what it's worth, I did a bit more rewriting to get this:

```
// mandelbrot.cpp
// compile with: g++ -std=c++11 mandelbrot.cpp -o mandelbrot
// view output with: eog mandelbrot.ppm

#include <fstream>
#include <complex> // if you make use of complex number facilities in C++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T> struct RGB { T r, g, b; };

template <class T>
struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;

    class proxy {
        Matrix &m;
        size_t index_1;
    public:
        proxy(Matrix &m, size_t index_1) : m(m), index_1(index_1) { }

        T &operator[](size_t index) { return m.data[index * m.rows + index_1]; }
    };

    class const_proxy {
        Matrix const &m;
        size_t index_1;
    public:
        const_proxy(Matrix const &m, size_t index_1) : m(m), index_1(index_1) { }

        T const &operator[](size_t index) const { return m.data[index * m.rows + index_1]; }
    };


public:
    Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : data(rows * cols), rows(rows), cols(cols) { }

    proxy operator[](size_t index) { return proxy(*this, index); }
    const_proxy operator[](size_t index) const { return const_proxy(*this, index); }

};

template <class T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Matrix<T> const &m) {
    out << "P6" << std::endl << m.cols << " " << m.rows << std::endl << 255 << std::endl;
    for (size_t y = 0; y < m.rows; y++)
        for (size_t x = 0; x < m.cols; x++) {
            T pixel = m[y][x];
            out << pixel.r << pixel.g << pixel.b;
        }
    return out;
}

/*Draw Mandelbrot according to the provided parameters*/
template <class T>
void draw_Mandelbrot(T & image, const unsigned width, const unsigned height, double cxmin, double cxmax, double cymin, double cymax, unsigned int max_iterations) {

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int ix = 0; ix < width; ++ix)
        for (int iy = 0; iy < height; ++iy)
        {
            std::complex<double> c(cxmin + ix / (width - 1.0)*(cxmax - cxmin), cymin + iy / (height - 1.0)*(cymax - cymin));
            std::complex<double> z = 0;
            unsigned int iterations;

            for (iterations = 0; iterations < max_iterations && std::abs(z) < 2.0; ++iterations)
                z = z*z + c;

            image[iy][ix].r = image[iy][ix].g = image[iy][ix].b = iterations;

        }
}

int main() {
    const unsigned width = 1600;
    const unsigned height = 1600;

    Matrix<RGB<unsigned char>> image(height, width);

    clock_t start = clock();
    draw_Mandelbrot(image, width, height, -2.0, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0, 255);
    clock_t stop = clock();

    std::cout << (double(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " seconds\n";

    std::ofstream out("mandelbrot.ppm", std::ios::binary);
    out << image;

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this code runs in about 0.5 to 0.6 seconds.

As to why I made these changes: mostly to make it faster, cleaner, and simpler. Your Matrix class allocated a separate block of memory for each row (or perhaps column--didn't pay very close of attention). This allocates one contiguous block of the entire matrix instead. This eliminates a level of indirection to get to the data, and increases locality of reference, thus improving cache usage. It also reduces the total amount of data used.

Changing from using `time` to using `clock` to do the timing was to measure CPU time instead of wall time (and typically improve precision substantially as well).

Getting rid of the PPMImage class was done simply because (IMO) having a PPImage class that derives from a Matrix class just doesn't make much (if any) sense. I suppose it works (for a sufficiently loose definition of "work") but it doesn't strike me as good design. If you insist on doing it at all, it should at least be private derivation, because you're just using the Matrix as a way of implementing your PPMImage class, not (at least I certainly hope not) trying to make assertions about properties of PPM images.

If, for whatever, reason, you decide to handle the threading manually, the obvious way of dividing the work up between threads would still be by looking at the loops inside of `draw_mandelbrot`. The obvious one would be to leave your outer loop alone, but send the computation for each iteration off to a thread pool:
        for (int ix = 0; ix < width; ++ix)
            compute_thread(ix);

where the body of `compute_thread` is basically this chunk of code:

```
        for (int iy = 0; iy < height; ++iy)
        {
            std::complex<double> c(cxmin + ix / (width - 1.0)*(cxmax - cxmin), cymin + iy / (height - 1.0)*(cymax - cymin));
            std::complex<double> z = 0;
            unsigned int iterations;

            for (iterations = 0; iterations < max_iterations && std::abs(z) < 2.0; ++iterations)
                z = z*z + c;

            image[iy][ix].r = image[iy][ix].g = image[iy][ix].b = iterations;

        }
```

There would obviously be a little work involved in passing the correct data to the compute thread (each thread should be pass a reference to a slice of the resulting picture), but that would be an obvious and fairly clean place to divide things up. In particular it divides the job up into enough tasks that you semi-automatically get pretty good load balancing (i.e., you can keep all the cores busy) but large enough that you don't waste massive amounts of time on communication and synchronization between the threads.

As to the result, with the number of iterations set to 255, I get the following (scaled to 25%):

[image]

...which is pretty much as I'd expect.

Comment: That's a huge improvement, I will look into OpenMP, but the main issue now is to divide the image into pieces and process this pieces with multiple threads. How to do that?

Comment: @Sybren: By inserting the pragma as above (i.e., that's exactly what OpenMP is doing).

Comment: inserted the pragma as you explained and replaced the main by your simplified main but `GIMP` shows this error now: `PNM Image Plug-in could not open image.` (I use `GIMP` to open the image)

Comment: @Sybren: I dunno--I did a bitwise comparison, and found the image I got was identical to what it produced before.

Comment: I see you did more rewriting then adding the pragma and simplify the main. U don't use the `PPMImage`class, what's the reason for that? I prefer to keep the program as much as possible identical to the code I posted.

Comment: I put your code into a seperate `C++ Console Application`. I'm using VS so I enabled OpenMP support and included `#include <omp.h>`. The code runs fine (except 2 warnings about comparing signed/unsigned) and for `10` iterations I get this result http://gyazo.com/56d231237d891357fc12dd94536d5da4 do you get the same result? This doesn't look like a Mandelbrot to me.

Comment: You're setting the color to the number of iterations at which the value 'escaped', but limiting that to 10, so your values are all between 0 and 10 (out of a maximum of 255) so it should look like nearly solid black (though if you look carefully, you *might* be able to see the basic outline of the set as *slightly* less dark than the inside parts). I've added an image of the result from setting the maximum iterations to 255 instead.

Comment: I use the most recent code from your post now, and we get the same results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you're using MSVC because `clock()` does not report the wall time with Unix. In general I would not recommend `clock()` I would recommend `omp_get_wtime()`.

Comment: @Zboson: You've misunderstood. The OP originally used `time`, which measures wall time. I changed it to use `clock` specifically so (assuming an implementation that isn't broken) it would measure CPU time instead. I don't think wall time is what anybody really wanted to measure here.

Comment: okay, why would you want the CPU time? I have not found a need for this. when profiling multithread apps I want the wall time.

Comment: @Zboson: I compare the single- vs. multi-threaded CPU time to see how much overhead I've added. Ideally, the CPU time remains roughly constant.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, that's interesting, I have not done that.

Answer (score 1):

One of the big issues with this approach is that different regions take different amounts of time to calculate.

A more general approach is.

- Start 1 source thread.
- Start N worker threads.
- Start 1 sink thread.
- Create 2 thread safe queues (call them the source queue and the sink queue).
- Divide the image into M (many more than N) pieces.
- The source thread pushes pieces into the source queue
- The workers pull piecse from the source queue, convert the pieces into result fragments, and pushes those fragments into the sink queue.
- The sink thread takes fragments from the sink queue and combines them into the final image.

By dividing up the work this way, all the worker threads will be busy all the time.

Comment: How to divide the image into pieces? I can't find any example.

Comment: @Sybren It's honestly difficult to believe you wrote code to draw a mandelbrot fractal but can't figure out how to divide a rectangular region into pieces. If you have a rectangle of width `w` and height `h` then you can trivially divide it into two rectangles of width `w/2` and height `h`, with one at an x-offset of `w/2` from the original. I'll leave further division as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the fractal into pieces by divide the start and end of the fractal with the screen dimension:

```
   $this->stepsRe = (double)((($this->startRe * -1) + ($this->endeRe)) / ($this->size_x-1));
   $this->stepsIm = (double)((($this->startIm * -1) + ($this->endeIm)) / ($this->size_y-1));
```

Comment: What in the world is `$this->` supposed to be? Are you trying to write PHP instead of C++?

Comment: Yes. Its PHP. But its not about language!?

Comment: The question *is* tagged C++. While the basic concept of the math isn't restricted to any one language, he did still ask fairly specifically for one language, and there seems to be no gain at all from using PHP instead.

Comment: IMO the question is how to subdivide the image.  He asked this several times in the comments.

Comment: Well, I guess if your intent were to generate a lot more heat, and produce the results a lot more slowly, this *would* probably be an effective way to do that...

Comment: No,  because once you subdivide the image you stop computation when its not useful. For example for a preview picture. But I agree there is better optimization.

Comment: While this certainly tries to divide into too many pieces, there's more to it than that--it also does the division fairly inefficiently. You're starting with a rectangular block. It's far easier to just divide that block into slices.